# (Rate of) Convergence in distribution and Laplace transform of random variables/stochastic processes

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t^n$ and $X_t$ be stochastic processes (with finite moments), and assume that for every $t>0$, $\lambda>0$ and bounded continuous function $\varphi$,
\begin{equation}
\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}E\varphi(X_s^n)d s\to\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}E\varphi(X_s)d s,\quad as \quad n\to\infty.
\end{equation}
Can we conclude that for every $t>0$,
$$
E\varphi(X_t^n)\to E\varphi(X_t),\quad as \quad n\to\infty ?
$$
A further question is that, if we know the rate of convergence, i.e., for a constant $C_0>0$,
$$
\bigg|\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}E\varphi(X_s^n)d s-\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}E\varphi(X_s)d s\bigg|\leq C_0\frac{1}{n},
$$
can we get
$$
\big|E\varphi(X_t^n)\to E\varphi(X_t)\big|\leq C_1\frac{1}{n} ?
$$
Thanks for your time and answer. Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: yes to first question, see Levy theorem for Laplace Transforms https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013425/the-continuity-theorem-with-respect-to-laplace-transform and proof in https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~amimica/lt.pdf and then use Portmanteau theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As to your first question, for the answer to be Yes you'll need some further hypotheses. For example, suppose $X^n_t(\omega) =0$ for all $n,t,\omega$; $X_t(\omega)=0$ for all $n,\omega$, and $t\not=1$ but $X_1$ has the standard normal distribution. Then
$$
\int_0^t e^{-\lambda s} E\varphi(X_s^n)\,ds - \int_0^t e^{-\lambda s} E\varphi(X_s)\,ds = \int_0^t e^{-\lambda s}\,ds\cdot \left[\varphi(0)-\varphi(0)\right]=0,
$$
for all $t$, $\lambda>0$, and bounded continuous $\varphi$, but $E\varphi(X^n_1)=\varphi(0)$ need not  converge to $E\varphi(X_1)$.